# More libraries in snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, editor

Could there be more libraries build-in in the snippets editor?
Maybe there are some CDN's (like https://cdnjs.com ) who have an API or wants to make some deal with SO. Then you could add a search-box at the top, so you can search and select an library to add.

I think if you add this feature, less people are going to use JSFiddler, JSBin or Bootply.
Not that's wrong to use these, but it's just easier to have an example in a snippet.

Comment: Yes, but you have to get the URL first somewhere. It would be a lot easier to search in the snippet editor for an library. For an example jQuery UI or Bootstrap.